# end javascript function after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript

I found a javascript snow script.  Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wj2K4/

(very nice)

Its only a gimmick and I don't want it dominating the page, so I want to turn it off after 10 or 30 seconds.

I reckon killing the script would be the easiest way, but I can't find a suitable command.  (or similar question on stack)

setTimeout() & setInterval() is not what I am looking for.

Ideas?

This code is pointless but I cant post the question without it:

```
function doStart() {
if (!s.excludeMobile || !isMobile) {
  if (s.freezeOnBlur) {
    s.events.add(isIE?document:window,'mousemove',doDelayedStart);
  } else {
    doDelayedStart();
  }
}
// event cleanup
s.events.remove(window, 'load', doStart);
  }
```

Comment: Why are setTimeout and setInterval not what you're looking for?

Comment: Call the toggleSnow() method inside setTimeout(), it'll turn off snow.

Comment: from w3 schools:  setInterval() - executes a function, over and over again, at specified time intervals.  I dont want to repeat a function.setTimeout() - executes a function, once, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds.  I want to end a function after time, not execute it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `s.stop();` to stop snow animations. See the code below, I used `setTimeout` to stop the animation

```
function doStart() {
  if (!s.excludeMobile || !isMobile) {
    if (s.freezeOnBlur) {
      s.events.add(isIE?document:window,'mousemove',doDelayedStart);
    } else {
      doDelayedStart();
    }
  }
  // event cleanup
  s.events.remove(window, 'load', doStart);
  setTimeout(function(){s.stop();},15000); //stop after 15 seconds
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/wj2K4/1/