# How to Stop a Javascript Function from running after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a specific sweet alert on my website that I use for my div class that opens with onclick, but I want this onclick alert to stop after 60 seconds for example. So after 60 seconds the alert won't show up if I click the div.THis is what I got so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function JSalert(){
    swal("Error", "You have to watch the video first.", "error");
}
</script>


<div class="blocked" onclick="JSalert()">
```

Comment: Can you use a timer timout? https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Please refer the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454830/end-javascript-function-after-10-seconds

Comment: Please confirm: Show an alert if user clicks div.  If user clicks div after 60 seconds, then don't show alert.

Comment: Instead of blocking the function, just remove the click handler from the button.

Comment: Refer http://jsfiddle.net/VQVxS/3/

Comment: Please do more research regarding the question before posting it in the StackOverflow.

Comment: This is an x/y problem imho. The question should be, how do I remove an event from a button instead of how do I stop an event from triggering. Now you still have a click event that gets executed, but will do nothing and hence, use browser resources for no good reason. I would suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/kLrfvy6c/3/

Comment: @Shilly why not add that as an answer?  removing the click event after 60s would certainly satisfy the question. But it's not an xy problem given your solution.

Comment: I was typing this as an answer when the question got flagged as a duplicate, hence preventing new answers from being posted.

Comment: @Cerbrus nominated as reopen as the duplicate is how to stop something that has started while this is how to stop something from starting after a certain time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand the question (and based on the translated text in the alert) :

- Give a warning if the user clicks the div
- after 60seconds (an eternity in web time (5s here for testing)) then don't show the alert when they click

(From OPs: "after 60 seconds the alert won't show up if I click the div" or, put another way, "the alert won't show up if I click the div after 60 seconds")

```js
var showalert = true;
setTimeout(function() { showalert = false; }, 5000);  /* 5s for testing */

function JSalert(){
  if (showalert) {
    alert("Please don't click too soon");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blocked" onclick="JSalert()">click me, but not too soon</div>
```

This could be improved using `data-` attributes / jquery `.data()`, but the concept is the same.

Comment: If I understood correctly what OP wants, this is the closest answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping a newbie, it works.You are so good

Answer (score -1):

What you lookin for is setTimeout: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Something like that in your JSalert function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // close modal here
}, 60000);
```

Or check the sweet alert docs there's also a timer:
https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#timer